# Is it possible to assign iterating property values to selected entities with a single declaration?

Tags: css

The code below demonstrates a document with 5 absolutely positioned divs of 5px by 5px dimension stacked on top of each other in z order by the blanket selector `.item`. Obviously the next step is to spread them out to the right. To do this I could simply add another class to each div; `.one` `.two` `.three.` `four.` `five`, and select them in the css `.one {}` `.two {}` `.three {}` `.four {}` `.five{}` apply variables and calculations. But there MUST be an easier way. I imagined up a way to iterate over child elements, assigning values in order, but obviously it did not work. I've provided an example below anyway.

So is there a way to do that, or at least to produce the same effect? If not, then what is the most efficient way to proceed?

Pure CSS is preferred for a task like this.

```css
.item {
  
  outline: 1px solid black; outline-offset: -1px;
  
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  
}

.item:nth-child(iterate[1]) {
  
  /*impression of desired effect*/
  left: 15px, 25px, 35px, 45px, 55px;

}

/*implementing a naive way*/
.i2 { left:0px; }
.i2 + .i2 { left:10px; }
.i2 + .i2 + .i2 { left:20px; }
.i2 + .i2 + .i2 + .i2 { left:30px; }
.i2 + .i2 + .i2 + .i2 + .i2 { left:40px; }

/*generic wrapper*/
.rel { position:relative; }
```

```html
non-functioning "iterative" version:
<div class="rel">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<br /><br />
Functioning individual-rules version (what I want):
<div class="rel">
    <div class="item i2"></div>
    <div class="item i2"></div>
    <div class="item i2"></div>
    <div class="item i2"></div>
    <div class="item i2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No this is not possible using "Pure" CSS. You need a pre-processor or Javascript.

Comment: Do they need to be positioned absolutely?

Comment: With SASS or LESS you can do it. Both of them are capable to make loops, and then it compiles in pure css without effort from you.

Comment: @j08691 They're positioned that way because that's how you control location. my local project has about 10 of them wrapped in another div, they're going to be used as a hotbar in a game. So I guess the answer is I don't know. If you have any ideas let me know.

Comment: Can you show us what the desired result should look like?

Comment: @Marcos Perez Gude --What do I need to use SASS or LESS? Does the browser just automatically support the syntax? do I need to download software? whats up?

Comment: @Musixauce3000 there aren't ideas for this. Your solutions pass from CSS pre-processor or Javascript

Comment: CSS is not a programming language. There aren't variables nor loops, conditionals, etc. There are some helpers that emulate some of them (for example the new variables, it calls variables but there isn't). CSS is as this, nothing more

Comment: SASS or LESS are CSS preproccessors, you write like a programming language, and then in the compilation it transforms to a pure CSS that's compatible with browsers. SASS and LESS syntax are not compatible with browsers. You must to investigate by yourself because stackoverflow is not a site for this purposes

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Wanting to tag you because I doubt you're gonna look back here otherwise. You actually _can_ do limitted iteration in CSS with certain properties: when the iteration is on a recursable property (one that "stacks" so to speak with its parent) and can be described recursively. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @abluejelly You can call "iterate" that, but it's not iterate. It's **nesting** the correct wording. As I said, CSS is not a programming language. Even the new variables in CSS are not variables, but emulate them. Are not variables because it doesn't change its values in execution time (maybe the best name should be constants).  In CSS are not loops, conditionals, or another programming language structure.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Nesting in the DOM is how you get a recursive tree which the CSS rule then _iterates_ over. You're using the wrong perspective- you can either focus on CSS only, which __does not support nesting__ or iteration in any way shape or form currently, or DOM only, in which case the CSS _can describe a recursive iteration_ which is then applied to any appropriate nested tree in the DOM. So if it's "nesting" __the CSS described a recursive iterator__.  And honestly, CSS is merely an arm of the HTML-DOM, describing it in terms of anything other than effect is extremely uninteresting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to not use `overflow:visible` or need them to actually be siblings in the dom instead of recursive descendants, you can just nest them. `pos:abs` anchors to the parent positioned object, so if your parent is `left:5px;`, and you're `left:5px;`, you're `left:10px;` from your grandparent.

```css
.item {
  outline: 1px solid black; outline-offset: -1px;
  
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;

  /*added "safety" rule (hence !important)*/
  overflow:visible !important;
}
.item .item {
  left: 5px;
  top: 0;
}
.item.i2 .item.i2{
  left:10px;
}

/*Because outline includes children even when positioned*/
.i3{
  outline:none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.i3 .i3{/*sync with border width*/
  top:-1px;
}

.rel{ position:relative; }
```

```html
Based on the left rules in the OP:
<div class="rel">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="item">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
Based on an edit suggestion for the "desired effect" by OP:<br />
<div class="rel">
    <div class="item i2">
        <div class="item i2">
            <div class="item i2">
                <div class="item i2">
                    <div class="item i2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
My fix to make the desired effect actually work: <br />
<div class="rel">
    <div class="item i2 i3">
        <div class="item i2 i3">
            <div class="item i2 i3">
                <div class="item i2 i3">
                    <div class="item i2 i3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's an interesting and potentially viable solution! I'm going to give it a few days before I accept this answer (I wanna see what other ideas are out there), but I very much like it :)

Comment: @Musixauce3000 Had to make a couple of tweaks, namely, can't use outline if you go nesting, have to use border. Reason being, outline includes children (as evident by the second version). I'll suggest an edit to your OP so it has a sample of the desired result and has the correct lefts- you went by 5s in your "like this" syntax.