# Better way to write this CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Each next H4 child is adding 10% to the top. Just curious if there is a better/nicer way to write this?

```
h4:nth-child(1){top: 0%}
h4:nth-child(2){top: 10%}
h4:nth-child(3){top: 20%;}
h4:nth-child(4){top: 30%;}
h4:nth-child(5){top: 40%;}
h4:nth-child(6){top: 50%;}
h4:nth-child(7){top: 60%;}
h4:nth-child(8){top: 70%;}
h4:nth-child(9){top: 80%;}

etc...
```

Comment: Maybe if you use preprocessors. With pure CSS, I don't think there is.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue, perhaps with an example?

Comment: why do you have so many `<h4>` elements and why aren't they being positioned in a relative manner?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not comfortable with saying you can just [define it as a recursive rule](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35897208/5116879) with `h4`s. Nesting `h4`s isn't something you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do it this way without using  preprocessors.

Alternate Suggestion is to use relative positioning(That can be defualt but depends on your css) like below

**Example:**

```css
div#relative h4 {
position:relative;
  top:10%
}
```

```html
<div id="relative">
  <h4>one</h4>
   <h4>two</h4>
   <h4>three</h4>
   <h4>four</h4>
   <h4>five</h4>
   <h4>six</h4>
   <h4>seven</h4>
   <h4>eight</h4>
</div>
```